# A single word meaning 'easy yet powerful'?

Tags: adjectives, british-english

I'm looking for a single adjective to describe a piece of software which is very easy to use, but has powerful features for users who have access and knowledge.

It's for a succinct marketing statement. The use would be something like this:

[easy yet powerful] images with your comments.

Hope that's clear, makes sense and some one has a good word.

Comment: I imagine that a powerful image conveys a powerful message, but what does it mean for an image to be easy?

Comment: Good point. It's easy for people to upload and comment on images.

Comment: Fundamentally then, *easy* applies to the comment process and *powerful* to the images.  The meaning you want is, 'Powerful, personalized images, easily.  I don't think a single adjective can do that.

Comment: You could be right that there is no one word to do this, so I've rewritten the sentence in a way which covers this meaning, and some other things too. Appreciate your help Jim. Both 'easy' and 'powerful' refer to the software, not so much images which the software might operate on. But, prognosis: it can't be done. Case closed!

Comment: [*Ivian*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Ive).

Comment: In my experience such software is usually called _[vapourware](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vapourware)_.

Comment: That software may be _enabling_; but that doesn't work with your statement.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean to find a term to describe your software (as being easy and powerful) rather than the image, which is presumably not being generated by your software.  In that case, you're likely intending top use a phrase like "image processing" or "image uploading" instead of "images".

At its core, I think your question is describing a common quandary in modern software marketing: the natural correlation between the two most common connotations of the term "simple" when used to describe software.  It can be used to mean "easy to use", but it can also be used to mean "lacking power or complexity".  It is often hard to find a term which implies the former without implying the latter.  Even "easy to use" itself has unfortunate connotations of lack of power.

The most common term I've seen used in this context is ***intuitive***, which implies ease of use without bringing any connotations of lack of functionality or power.  It doesn't itself also imply any particular level of power, so it doesn't actually connote "powerful", but by the absence of a connotation of weakness it can feel more powerful in marketing language.  It certainly sounds more elegant, advanced, and valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Not a single word, but "Powerfully easy" would be good marketing. Or perhaps Superbly easy? How about Easy as 1-2-3. Powerful, yet easy as 1-2-3. You'd never imagine that powerful images could be made that easy!

Answer (score 0):

**Effortless**

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=effortless) says

> Calling for, requiring, or showing little or no effort. See Synonyms at [easy](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=E5017400).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest two words.

The first one is a variation of the word "Imagination", more specifically "Imaginative". Because [this word] conveys positive emotions and, hopefully, invites the user to try things. It hints that the limit is the imagination of the user.

The second one is a variation of the word "Open" or "Openness" but this takes context in case of games or gamification scenarios, where a game is "Open-World" if it has a final objective but hints that there are other actions that the user can perform while in the game. Another alternative is when a game is "Open-Ended", it means that there are many endings depending on the user's actions or decisions.